# Port closed error even after opening it with ufw

Tags: networking, server, firewall, ufw, nodejs

I just created an Ubuntu Server on Digital Ocean for a NodeJS SMTP email project. I am getting an error in my `pm2 logs` when I start up the server via `sudo pm2 start npm -- start`:

```
0|npm      | Error listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:587
```

Which I would assume means that the port `586` is blocked/closed. I have tried to open the port by running `sudo ufw allow 587` and when I run `sudo ufw status` I get this:

```
22                         LIMIT       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere
587                        ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)                    LIMIT       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
587 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Which says 587 is open. However, when I run `nmap localhost` `nmap` says the port `587` isn't open:

```
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
1234/tcp open  hotline
3000/tcp open  ppp
```

Why would I still be getting this npm error and why isn't `ufw` actually opening port `587`?

Comment: Did you reload ufw?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I've tried resetting it before the new rule if that's what you mean?

Comment: That looks like a npm error and not a problem with ufw . If you feel it is due to ufw, disable ufw and try again.